# Linux numbers/figures before the user's and group's names

Tags: linux, shell, permissions

After thorough research online, I've struggled to figure out what the NUMBERS BEFORE USER's NAME on linux mean and how we can change it ? This is for classroom homework purpose.

I'll explain myself clearer with the following example. After a ls-l, I got this:

" drwxr-xr-x  2   John   Family  2048  June 14  "

**Here's my question** Does anybody know what does the "2" before John mean ? Can we change that number with a specific command line ? Maybe chmod ?

Please note, I'm very new to developing as a general (just have a few basics in C language) and stackoverflow so I may be very clumsy in my approach.

Thanks guys in advance for those who would be willing to shed some light on the darkness of my novice-ness ahah

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about `ls` from the man page that you can read at `man ls`. In particular, look for the section that will be labelled `The Long Format`, which goes into much detail. On my system (OS X 10.10) it reads as follows:

> If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for
>   each file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number
>   of bytes in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last
>   modified, hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the
>   pathname.

In general, you find details about Unix commands with the `man` command.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for being SO quick ! I'll try that out right away

Comment: Just one question, how do you get the confidence/faith you may find an answer by searching using man?

I mean, even though you may know the problem, you may not necessarily know what "man" to type. And there are endless command lines you can type "man" with.

Comment: The man system is not particularly difficult to navigate, but it's large. The first place to go is the name of the command that you are are looking to get more information about. If you don't know the name of the command, then `man -k` or `apropos` will do a search for you. It's also helpful to know that user commands are in section 1 of the man pages, file formats are in section 5, and system commands are in section 8.

Comment: Great thank you ! By the way, I found the answer thanks to you ! the number correponds to the number of links (hardlinks or symbolic links) and this number can be influenced by the command "ln" or (for a symbolic link) "ln -s". Thanks again vielmetti

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to you ! the number correponds to the number of links (hardlinks or symbolic links) and this number can be influenced by the command "ln" or (for a symbolic link) "ln -s". Thanks again vielmetti – Zel just now   edit